# MySQL insert number of repeated word to column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with repeated words and an empty field named by "num".

```
+----+--------------+-----+
| id | words        | num |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 1  | red          |     |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 2  | blue         |     |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 3  | red          |     |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 4  | red          |     |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 5  | blue         |     |
+----+--------------+-----+
```

I want to insert number of repeated words in num field like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----+
| id | words        | num |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 1  | red          | 1   |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 2  | blue         | 1   |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 3  | red          | 2   |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 4  | red          | 3   |
+----+--------------+-----+
| 5  | blue         | 2   |
+----+--------------+-----+
```

how can I do this by php or sql?

Comment: Is the list fixed or still growing?

Comment: list is fixed, and I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for `MySQL`.

You can join a subquery which generates a rownumber on every `words` based on the `ID` using correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE  tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.id, 
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    tableName c
                        WHERE   c.words = a.words AND
                                c.id <= a.id
                    ) AS RowNumber
            FROM    TableName a
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
SET     a.num = b.rownumber
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3badd/1)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be an easy way to achieve it:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_colors ( 
   id int auto_increment primary key,
   word varchar(16) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmp_colors SELECT words FROM table GROUP BY words;

UPDATE table t1 JOIN tmp_colors t2 ON t2.word = t1.words SET t1.num = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If DBMS supports window functions (like Oracle or MS SQL Server):

```
select id,word,row_number() over(partition by word order by id)
from t1 
order by id;
```